# NAT in simple home LAN

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

I have a simple LAN at home. The LAN-side computers have by default an access to the WAN (internet). By default i mean i didn't changed/configured anything in the modem/router connecting the LAN to  WAN. Is i'm right that in case i've described - where the connection is initiated from LAN side there is automatically enabled port-based NAT on the modem/router while allowing WAN-side to access LAN requires explicit configuration in the modem/router panel (forwarding section)?

Comment: If you mean accessing devices behind the router from outside, then yes, you have to set forwarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. NAT or call it PAT is usually configured by default as this is what your router is made for. But if you want to make services/ports accessible from the Internet, you need to activate and configure port forwarding (port to port). For example if you have a web server running on one of your desktops/laptops and you want to make it available on the Internet, and assume your desktop has an IP address of 192.168.1.100 and you are running then web server on port 8080, the you need to forward port 80 (http) to your IP address 192.168.1.100 port 8080.

Be aware of security risks as you are exposing you LAN to the outside.